# Defining a scala Map of functions with variable return types

Tags: scala

Is it possible to generalize the return types of a Map of functions with variable return types to a common signature and then use the actual return type of each function in the Map at runtime?

Explanation:

I'm having a scala Map of string -> functions defined as:

```
Map[String, (String) => Seq[Any]] = Map("1" -> foo, 2 -> bar, 3 -> baz)
```

where foo, bar and baz are defined as:

```
foo(string: String): Seq[A]
bar(string: String): Seq[B]
baz(string: String): Seq[C]
```

The compilation works fine but at runtime Seq[A or B or C] types returned by the functions are being treated as Seq[Any] thereby giving me a reflection exception.

Comment: Will you always have only two possible return types, A and B, or is it possible for there to be many?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @mattinbits there will be more than two. Sorry for not being clear about that in the question. If it was limited to 2, I could've used Either[A, B]

Comment: @dcastro You're right in that my actual problem led me to this issue and right now I'm more interested in this issue than the actual issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine some Map-alike workaround

Suppose we define type like that

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class PolyMap[K, V[+_]] {
  var backing = Map[(K, TypeTag[_]), V[Any]]()

  def apply[T: TypeTag](key: K) =
    backing.get(key, typeTag[T]).asInstanceOf[Option[V[T]]]

  def update[T: TypeTag](key: K, f: V[T]): this.type = {
    backing += (key, typeTag[T]) → f
    this
  }
}
```

now having

```
type String2Seq[+X] = String ⇒ Seq[X]
val polyMap = new PolyMap[String, String2Seq]

polyMap("foo") = foo
polyMap("bar") = bar
```

you could ensure that

```
polyMap[String]("foo").map(_("x")) == Some(foo("x"))
polyMap[Int]("foo").map(_("x")) == None
polyMap[Int]("bar").map(_("x")) == Some(bar("x"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this variant

```
def foo(string: String): Seq[String] = {
 Seq(string)
}

def bar(string: String): Seq[Int] = {
 Seq(1)
}
val map = Map(1 -> foo _, 2 -> bar _)
val res = map(1) match {
    case f: (String => Seq[String]) => f
    case f: (String => Seq[Int]) => f
    case _ => throw new NotImplementedError()
}

println(res("Hello"))
```

it work's for me.

Comment: This does work. Only that this requires matching the result against all possible return types again. Is it possible to avoid the same? Thanks for this.

Comment: It's not clear what is acheved here. `res` is still of type `Seq[Any]`. Also first and second case clauses are equivalent after type erasure, so second will never be matched

Comment: @Odomontois you are right. I missed that res wil be `Seq[Any]`

Comment: @sheff_master Actually it will be `Function1[_, _]`